# Accessing a UNC share on a web server is causing a WebDAV PROPFIND request

Tags: iis, webdav, unc, propfind

Since a recent web server migration to Windows Server 2019, when someone tries to access files in a UNC share remotely via VPN (programmatically or via File Explorer) , it causes a WebDAV request with the PROPFIND method. The UNC share is not inside the web root, is not listed as a virtual directory, and is not even on the same drive. These requests to not occur when accessing the share from inside our network.

- WebDAV Publishing is not installed in the Add Roles and Features UI (Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Common HTTP Features > WebDAV Publishing)
- WebDAV is not listed as an installed module in IIS

What is causing these requests, and how can I prevent them? I just want the UNC share to be a normal shared folder - not accessible from the web.

User-Agent making the requests: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18363

Comment: `Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir` is the so called WebDAV Redirector, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-webdav/using-the-webdav-redirector and it is part of default Windows installation so you cannot turn it off.

Comment: @LexLi I didn't map the share to a URL though, so I can't figure out why going to the share in File Explorer is causing a web request.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.